# Create Java App Install Package

Tags: java, deployment, intellij-idea

First, I did look through the list of suggested questions generated by the keywords in my question but did not find anything relevant or helpful.

New to Java programming (not new to programming) so I don't know what useful tools there might be out there.  I have a java console app, written using the intellij IDE.  After testing and debugging, I am ready to deploy for a demo.  Didn't find anything in the IDE that would let me do this!

I would now like to create a couple of installers - one for windows and one for linux.  What do I do?  I gather I just need the classfiles, but it would be nice to create an icon which would call the app with the right commandline options for the java.exe.  As well, I have dependencies on log4j and jnetpcap (.dll requirements there)... how do I handle getting those support libs deployed - can I use the same installer or do I install them separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First things first**, you need to JAR those class files.  This is the standard way to package files in Java.  A typical command would be:

```
jar cvf MyApp.jar *.class
```

Next you need to add a manifest to the JAR indicating the entry point into your program.  Create a file called manifest.txt and add this line:

```
Main-Class: MyApp
```

MyApp would refer to the class name that contains the `main()` method.  Now make the JAR again, this time specifying the manifest:

```
jar cvfm MyApp.jar manifest.txt *.class
```

On Windows, you can look into using [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/).  You can use it to wrap your JAR in a EXE and specify that it runs as a non-GUI, console app.

In Linux, you can include a shell script along with your JAR to execute it.  Place the script in your path.  For example:

```
#!/bin/bash
java -jar MyApp.jar
```

It would be additional work to add dependent libraries to the mix as well as create installers.  Seems too broad to include all in one question, but hopefully this will get you started.

Comment: Hmmm... jar file eh?  Okay, I found [this guide](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/) over at JetBrains to let me create a jar.  With a bit of random stabbing at the keyboard and a whole lotta "What happens if I push this?", I was even able to shoehorn in the JAR-ry bits from the jnetpcap and log4j jars as well.  Only thing I haven't figured out yet is how to get some DLLs and other files (log4j config file, batch file to run app, etc.) copied and placed alongside.

Comment: @Jon Sounds like you're on the right track.  You are right that the IDE can do the JARing for you.  Unfortunately, I'm an Eclipse user, not IDEA, so I can't be much more help there.